# How to cin whole sentence with whitespaces

Tags: c++, char, cin

I have tried:

```
    char tab[200];
    cin>>tab;
    cout<<tab<<endl;
```

and I would like to make that even if I input in console `A B C` all the 3 chars and spaces go into `tab` at once .

Comment: You want `getline` probably.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`cin.getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) instead:

```
char tab[200];
cin.getline(input,200);
cout<<tab<<endl;
```

Comment: `input` or `tab`?

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`std::getline(cin, tab)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

Comment: Actually `std::getline(std::cin, tab);`. Or, if `using namespace std`, it should be `getline(cin, tab);`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `std::getline`, specifying whatever character you want to mark the end of the sentence (e.g., '.').

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to do a getline in some form.

```
string str;
cin.get(str, 25);
cout <<"\"" <<str <<"\"" <<endl;
```

or

```
string str;
cin.getline(str, 25);
cout <<"\"" <<str <<"\"" <<endl;
```

Both accept a third parameter, a char, that specifies what to consider the end of the line. For details see http://www.minich.com/education/wyo/cplusplus/cplusplusch10/getfunction.htm

Comment: This is C++ - where's your `std::string`?