# Why do I get 0 after I hit enter on this C++ code

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve this problem http://a2oj.com/p?ID=24. However when I try to accept test cases, after typing the test case number and hitting enter, the console window displays a 0.
My code:

```
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int t; //test cases
  string str;
  cin >> t;
  while(t--){
    std::getline (cin,str);
    int len = str.size();
    cout << len;
  }
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to search for this anywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cin whole sentence with whitespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446951/how-to-cin-whole-sentence-with-whitespaces)

Comment: The website defining the problem might not be up when someone later finds your question: SO rules for posting questions oblige you to properly define your question on *this* site, so it'll certainly be available for future readers.

Comment: In answer to your edited question: after cin >> t, there is still a "\n" in the buffer, so the next getline call returns the remaining string up to that which will mostly likely be empty, so we get a "0" (try adding some spaces after the number before pressing enter and see what happens!).  After the call to cin >> t, you need to ignore the "\n": cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `std::getline(string)` function. See this sample code:

```
// extract to string
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    int main ()
    {
      std::string name;

      std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
      std::getline (std::cin,name);
      std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";

      return 0;
    }
```